# diagonizable vs orthogonally diagonizable

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

prove a symmetric matrix is diagonalizable without doing any calculations of eigenvalues or eigenvectors.

I know its orthogonally diagonalizable but is that the same as diagonalizable?

Comment: What does orthogonally diagonalizable mean?  What does diagonalizable mean?  I think if you write out these definitions, you will immediately see that orthogonally diagonalizable implies diagonalizable.

Comment: Okay, i thought so because orthogonally diagonalizable is just a special case of diagonalizable